# Open .ica file automatically?

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

When I download an `.ica` file through Chrome I get a popup in the bottom left hand corner saying it has been downloaded. I have to click that to have it open in in the `Citrix Workspace` Chrome OS app.

Is there any way I can have this automatically open in Chrome OS?

Answer (score 1):

Just installed this tonight on new chromeboook. When the ica file downloads, click on it and it will open in the "download" folder. At the top, just to the right of center there should be an open button, click on that and there should be at least two choice, text and citrix receiver. Choose Citrix Receiver and you should be good to go.

Comment: I am about to open the file, however I would like it to automatically open with Citrix Workspaces without me having to click anything - this is the behaviour I had on windows.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the download bar:

After downloading one ICA file, click the drop-down list for the file in the
download bar and select *Always Open Files of This Type*:

[image]

Comment: I don't have a download bar...can't see anything in the "Downloads" list to allow me to do this either.

Comment: You might try to [reset Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en).

Comment: It's a fresh Chromebook :). I contacted Google support, apparently they don't have this feature on Chrome OS - perhaps its a security thing?

Comment: It's part of the Chrome user interface. Seems strange if it's missing on the Chromebook. Maybe some extension is hiding it?